# Transformation not reproducible

Tags: real-analysis, integration, partial-differential-equations

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \supset \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ and $u:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. 
>   For 
>   $$\mathrm{div} \Bigg (\frac{\nabla u}{\sqrt{1+|\nabla u|^2}}\Bigg) =0$$ 
>   let $u_1,u_2$ be two solutions. I want to show that $v := u_1 - u_2$ is a solution of the form 
>   $\mathrm{div} (A\nabla v)=0$ for a positive definite and symmetric matrix $A$.

The only advice given is to introduce the function
$$
F(X):=\frac{X}{\sqrt{1+|X|^2}}
$$
and use a green formula for
$$
F(b)-F(a)=\int_0^1\partial_tF(ta+(1-t)b)\,\mathrm{d}t.
$$

**Attempt:**
When choosing $X=\nabla u_{1,2}$ and using linearity of the divergence I get

$$
\mathrm{div}\left (F(\nabla u_1)-F(\nabla u_2)\right )
= 0
= \mathrm{div}\int_0^1\partial_tF(t\nabla u_2+(1-t)\nabla u_1)\,\mathrm{d}t.
$$

Here I am stuck as I don't find a suiting Green formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you need to compute.  First note that 
$$
\partial_t F(t X + (1-t) Y) = DF(tX + (1-t)Y)(X-Y), 
$$
which in particular means that 
$$
\partial_t F(t \nabla u_2 + (1-t) \nabla u_1) = DF(t\nabla u_2 + (1-t)\nabla u_1)(\nabla u_2-\nabla u_1).
$$

Returning to your formula, we note that $\nabla u_2 - \nabla u_1$ is independent of $t$, so
$$
0 = \text{div} \left( \left[\int_0^1 DF(t\nabla u_2 + (1-t)\nabla u_1) dt\right] (\nabla u_2-\nabla u_1) \right)
$$
and we get the desired result by setting
$$
A = \int_0^1 DF(t\nabla u_2 + (1-t)\nabla u_1) dt.
$$
To get more specific information about $A$ (ellipticity, etc), we need to compute $DF$.  First note
$$
\partial_j F(X)_k = \frac{ \sqrt{1+ |X|^2}  \delta_{jk} - X_k X_j/ \sqrt{1 + |X|^2} }{1+ |X|^2},
$$
which we can rewrite as
$$
DF(X) = \frac{I}{(1+|X|^2)^{1/2}} - \frac{X \otimes X}{(1+ |X|^2)^{3/2}}.
$$
We can then plug in above to get more information about $A$.

EDIT: As requested, here is some more information about $A$.

It's obvious that $A$ is symmetric since $DF(\cdot)$ is.  Let $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and note that 
$$
DF(X) z \cdot z = \frac{|z|^2}{(1+|X|^2)^{1/2}} - \frac{|X \cdot z|^2}{(1+ |X|^2)^{3/2}} = \frac{|z|^2 + |z|^2|X|^2 - |z\cdot X|^2 }{(1+ |X|^2)^{3/2}} \ge \frac{|z|^2}{(1+ |X|^2)^{3/2}},
$$
where the last inequality follows from Cauchy-Schwarz.  Next note that
$$
|t \nabla u_2 + (1-t) \nabla u_1| \le \Vert \nabla u_2\Vert_{L^\infty} + \Vert \nabla u_1\Vert_{L^\infty} =: C_0,
$$
which means that
$$
(1+ |t \nabla u_2 + (1-t) \nabla u_1|^2)^{3/2} \le (1+ C_0^2)^{3/2}.
$$
Then
$$
A z \cdot z \ge |z|^2 \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{(1+ |t \nabla u_2 + (1-t) \nabla u_1|^2)^{3/2}} \ge \frac{|z|^2}{(1+ C_0^2)^{3/2}},
$$
and we have that $A$ is elliptic with the ellipticity constant depending on $\nabla u_i$ via the constant $C_0$.

Comment: Very elegant! If I wanted to prove ellipticity then I would have to show that this matrix is positiv definite and symmetric. Symmetry follows immediately from commutativity of the tensor product for commutative rings. Do you have an idea for showing the pos. def. property?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta I'm glad you like it.  See the edit for ellipticity.